# how to stop UIProgrssView?

Tags: iphone

i have implemented UIProgressview in my application?But i dont know how to start and stop.Can u advice me for this question?

Answer (score 2):

```
[myProgressView setProgress:newValueOfProgress];
```

newValueOfProgress is a float between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: Yes, you don't "start" or "stop" a progress view, you simply update its value.  When done, you remove it from the interface.